# using a single Dynamodb resource in terraform and create 3 tables with different names

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-dynamodb, terraform-provider-aws, infrastructure

I have a used case where,
I need to create 3 dynamodb tables but only the naming convention changes

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "GB_SKU_COLOR" {
  name         = "GB_SKU_COLOR_${var.stage}"
  billing_mode = "PAY_PER_REQUEST"
  hash_key     = "PRODUCT_ID"
  stream_enabled   = true
  stream_view_type = "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"
  attribute {
    name = "PRODUCT_ID"
    type = "S"
  }
}
```

I need to create the same table with 2 different names, like MN_SKU_COLOR and CH_SKU_COLOR
Currently, am replicating the resource and giving a new name

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "MN_SKU_COLOR" {
      name         = "MN_SKU_COLOR_${var.stage}"
      billing_mode = "PAY_PER_REQUEST"
      hash_key     = "PRODUCT_ID"
      stream_enabled   = true
      stream_view_type = "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"
      attribute {
        name = "PRODUCT_ID"
        type = "S"
      }
    }

resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "CH_SKU_COLOR" {
      name         = "CH_SKU_COLOR_${var.stage}"
      billing_mode = "PAY_PER_REQUEST"
      hash_key     = "PRODUCT_ID"
      stream_enabled   = true
      stream_view_type = "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"
      attribute {
        name = "PRODUCT_ID"
        type = "S"
      }
    }
```

What is the best way to create the resource 3 times without replicating the code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the only difference is in name, then you can do:

```
variable "names" {
  default = ["MN_SKU_COLOR", "GB_SKU_COLOR", "CH_SKU_COLOR"]
}


resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "table" {
   
      for_each     = toset(var.names)  
   
      name         = "${each.key}_${var.stage}"
      billing_mode = "PAY_PER_REQUEST"
      hash_key     = "PRODUCT_ID"
      stream_enabled   = true
      stream_view_type = "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"
      attribute {
        name = "PRODUCT_ID"
        type = "S"
      }
    }
```

Then you refer to the individual tables using their name from variabile, e.g.

```
aws_dynamodb_table.table["MN_SKU_COLOR"].id
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `for_each` along with a set or list of names: https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each